# How to Turn off automatic saving on web storm

Tags: editor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am developing with meteor and Webstorm, being that meteor automatically updates the browser and Webstorm saves after you stop typing. It gets annoying. I checked my preferences and I can see that I have 'save automatically' unchecked. How do I completely stop the auto save feature in web storm ?

Comment: Do you use any file watcher in this project? When immediate synchronization is enabled for a file watcher, files will be saved automatically.

Comment: I don't think i am using any file watcher at all. I know that meteor just updates the browser on any file changes and that my webstorm files get saved after i stop typing

Comment: Can you confirm that [these 2 options](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/7817/20130325031539.png) are disabled?

Comment: Ah, i had the first one enabled. I think its working now. I feel a little lagging as i am typing but that might be something else. Post it as an answer so i can accept. Thanks

Comment: OMG 8 years ago!!!

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Automatic save can be disabled using the following options:

> File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings > Uncheck these boxes below:
>
> - Save files on frame deactivation
> - Save files automatically if application is idle for...

[image: Save options]

Be aware that File Watchers feature may override this behavior for the specific file types (if enabled).

Save will also occur automatically on certain actions (running a configuration, IDE quit, project close, etc).

You may want to [enable the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g35RP.png) to mark modified files with `*`.

Comment: Its really weird, on stopping and starting meteor locally, if the files in webstorm have not been saved. It removes all changes made to the actively open file

Comment: Only happens on my javascript files

Comment: That is weird because WebStorm should show you a file conflict notification when you have unsaved changes in the editor. You can verify it by editing a file in WebStorm, without saving edit it in some other editor and save there. Go back to WebStorm, it will warn you about the conflict.

Comment: Okay. I will give that shot, i had to close it down and try it again. Its not really happening anymore. Thanks again

Comment: FYI, to disable this behaviour for file watchers, uncheck the `Immediate file synchronization` checkbox.

Comment: There's certainly something odd about filewatchers. I enabled a coffeescript filewatcher and now get the "constant restart" problem despite unchecking all I can see... there's even a checkbox to turn watchers off which seems to have no effect. Yep, autosave is evil for meteor.

Comment: refer to anchal20's answer for the current correct answer

Comment: @JeffWilkerson thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer from 2013 to reflect the new settings path in 2020.

Comment: what is the meaning of "frame deactivation"

Comment: @NullByte08 when you switch from the IDE to some other app (using Alt+Tab or any other way), in other words, when the application window loses focus.

Answer (score 68):

It seems there is no way to make Webstorm 9 behaving like a standard text editor.

The closer you can get is:

- Settings / Appearance & Behavior / System Settings / Save file on frame deactivation: **unchecked**
- Settings / Appearance & Behavior / System Settings / Save files automatically if...: **unchecked**
- Settings / Editor / General / Editor tabs / Mark modified tabs with asterisk : **checked**

The resulting behavior is:

- Changes are not automatically saved in the file
- If you close a changed file, no warning is displayed
- If you close a changed file then reopen it, changes have not been lost

See also this discussion:
http://www.dotmana.com/weblog/2012/07/disable-auto-save-in-phpstorm/

Comment: Right answer :)

Comment: This is really stupid and annoying.  It should be up to the user if they want to autosave.

Comment: When everything is turned off, it even shows the asterisk when reopening it, but when closing and opening the project it is suddenly saved. What a joke. (Version 2019.2)

Answer (score 15):

For Webstorm version 2018.2
Build #WS-182.3684.70, built on July 20, 2018

GOTO => Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Uncheck 'Save files on frame deactivation' and also Uncheck the next option

This will stop automatic save

[image: Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Uncheck 'Save files on frame deactivation']

If you want some kind of distinguishing factor to know if the file has been modified then do the following :

GOTO => Settings -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs -> Check 'Mark modified (*)
[image]

Answer (score 12):

In WebStorm 10, autosave settings are here: File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings

Comment: In WebStorm 2016.2.3 Build #WS-162.1812.21, from september 2016 the path is the same as in WebStorm 10 --> File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings and then see Options under Synchronisation

Answer (score 9):

**MacOS WebStorm 2016.2**: menu> Webstorm> Preferences> Apppearance&Behavior> SystemSettings> Right panel: Synchronization> And uncheck:

> Save files on frame deactivation
>
> Save files automatically if application is idle for...

Comment: For clarity, it is better to "Mark modified tabs with asterisk". You can turn on this option by:

File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs

Answer (score 3):

## Disable Auto Save

> `File` > `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Synchronization` > then uncheck both `Save files on frame deactivation` and `Save files automatically if application is idle` > `OK`

[image: Screenshot- Disable Auto Save]

---

<sub>Now, you may want to do this too.</sub>

## Mark Changed But Unsaved File

> `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Editor Tabs` > then check `Mark modified tabs with asterisk` > `OK`

[image: Screenshot- Mark Changed But Unsaved File]

## Save One File with Ctrl+S

> `File` > `Settings` > `Keymap` > search with **save document** > right click `Save Document` > `Add Keyboard Shortcut` > press **Ctrl+S**> `OK` > `Remove` > `OK`

[image: Screenshot- Save One File with Ctrl+S]

Answer (score 1):

### Only works prior to 2022.

I am running `Node.js` so I had to uncheck `Update Node.js application on changes`.
There is also a `Update application in Chrome on changes`.

> Got to `"Build, Execution, Deployment" > Debugger > Live Edit`

[image]

Comment: 2022 This is not valid anymore. THe options doesn't work.

Comment: Then what does?

Comment: then it stops auto updating?

Answer (score 0):

In web storm 2017.3.4
File->Setting->System Setting->Syncronization
unchecked all check boxes then apply and ok .

[screen shot on setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaer5.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using **Flow** type checking in their code, in addition to the above answers, there is a separate auto-save setting for JS Flow files in WebStorm.

1. Go to Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript
2. If your JavaScript language version is set to **Flow**, there will be a setting to **Save all modified files automatically**. Uncheck this.